# Check all/uncheck all - checkboxes and tabular data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using [Footables](http://themergency.com/footable/) to display tabular data. Each row has a checkbox. There is one master checkbox that selects all. I am running into some difficulties. The table has a filter. When I apply the filter and try to check all checkboxes within that filter it wont work. Also, since I am able to check all checkboxes at once is there away to uncheck all checkboxes? [EXAMPLE](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/footable/demos/showcase2.htm)

Checkbox function

```
$(document).on('change','input[name="check_all"]',function() {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', true);
    });
    $(document).on('change','select',function() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);
    });
```

table filter

```
$(function () {
        $('table').footable().bind({
            'footable_filtering': function (e) {
                var selected = $('.filter-status').find(':selected').text();
                if (selected && selected.length > 0) {
                    e.filter += (e.filter && e.filter.length > 0) ? ' ' + selected : selected;
                    e.clear = !e.filter;
                }
            },
            'footable_filtered': function() {
                var count = $('table.demo tbody tr:not(.footable-filtered)').length;
                $('.row-count').html(count + ' rows found');
            }
        });

        $('.clear-filter').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.filter-status').val('');
            $('table.demo').trigger('footable_clear_filter');
            $('.row-count').html('');
        });

        $('.filter-status').change(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('table.demo').data('footable-filter').filter( $('#filter').val() );
        });
    });
```

Comment: use `.prop` instead of `.attr`

Answer (score 2):

- use .prop() instead of .attr()
- Check/uncheck only the visible rows
- set the checked status to the select all checkboxes state

Try

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="check_all"]', function () {
    $(".footable tr:visible input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Great! my real table is a lot bigger, therefore has several pagination with filter applied. Your technique only checks all checkboxes on the first page and not the other pages.

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student how is the paging done... whether the data is loaded via ajax

Comment: For example if you check with firebug when applying a filter certain rows are hidden and have a class of `footable-filtered`, with the function above i just want to check checkboxes only in the filtered result.

Answer (score 1):

try this one with `not` selecter which will select except the class `.footable -filtered`

```
 $(document).on('change', 'input[name="check_all"]', function () {
            $(".footable tr:not(.footable-filtered) input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', this.checked);

        });
```

Comment: The thing is that this still checks the checkboxes that are hidden because of filter.

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student so wot u want? should not check hidden ones?

Comment: Correct, not check hidden ones. For example if you check with firebug when applying a filter certain rows are hidden and have a class of `footable-filtered`, with the function above when checking all, it selects everything in the filtered result PLUS what is hidden from the filter.

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student check the edited code is this ll wrk for u??

Comment: It is still checking all, check [EXAMPLE](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/footable/demos/showcase2.htm) I place an alert to show the total number of boxes checked.

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student sorry there had a mistake, remove space between `tr` and `not` check answer its edited.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48336/discussion-between-chriz-and-code-ed-student)